# dealing with multiple lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have written a Python script to manipulate data in multiple files and create up to 9 new files as outputs. To do this I create 9 different lists which I then write to up to 9 different files (depending if the lists contain any items).

My code is quite repetitive eg:

```
if list1 != []:
   newfile1 = open(os.path.join(dirpath,"newlist1.txt"),'w')
   for i in list1:
      newfile1.write(i)
   newfile1.close() 

if list2 != []:
   newfile2 = open(os.path.join(dirpath,"newfile2.txt"),'w')
   for i in list2:
      newfile2.write(i)
   newfile2.close()
```

..... for 9 different lists
I'm just curious mainly for my own development could I have done this in a more efficient way? I loop through files in a directory to create the lists, but can I loop through the lists in memory to create the output files?

I probably should have created a function for the file writing but then I'm not sure how to deal with the different output filenames it'd need to create? Each list has a different output name - create different variables? Would that end up more efficient still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of lists `lsts`, such as:

```
lsts = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

then you can do:

```
for i, lst in enumerate(lsts, 1):
    if lst:
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath,"newfile{}.txt".format(i)), 'w') as f:
            for elem in lst:
                f.write(elem)
```

Checking if list is not empty can be done with `if lst` (empty list is false). Also using the `with` context for opening files doesn't require to close it explicitely afterwards.

EDIT: It may be more logical to build a dictionary (so you have the filename and data together):

```
d = {'file1.txt': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
     'file2.txt': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
     'file3.txt': ['g', 'h', 'i']}

for filename, lst in d.iteritems():
    if lst:
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), 'w') as f:
            for elem in lst:
                f.write(elem)
```

Comment: Thanks.. I'm getting my head round the naming part.... is your code suggesting I use a dictionary of file names and use the increment of the list it's looking at to name them?

Comment: @CarmenC - my answer gives them incremental names. But a dictionary might be more appropriate.

Comment: Great suggestion in the edit. Thanks very much!! I probably wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: I've done it in a similar way way above, but with two lists , one list_of_lists, and another list with names, using the list index of the list_of_lists  to pick the name of the file in the for loop from the second name list. I couldn't figure how to get the dictionary key to work as the file name

Answer (score 1):

You could still write a function but you'd probably have to give it a few parameters and specify what to call in each:

```
def writeToFile(listname, fileName = "newlist1.txt"):
    if not listname:
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, fileName) , "w") as myFile:
            for x in listname:
                myFile.write(x)
```

and then, if you choose this solution, go ahead and just call this 9 times. But, on the first call, the 2nd parameter has been finished for you.

```
writeToFile(list1)
writeToFile(list2, "newList2.txt")
```

etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's the way I was thinking of doing it if I used a function, just needed confirmation that using parameters was the way to go.